# addressing a numerical column name in R dplyr using a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some column names as numbers:

```
> names(spreadResults)
 [1] "PupilMatchingRefAnonymous" "GENDER"                    "URN"                      
 [4] "KS2Eng"                    "KS2Mat"                    "EVERFSM_6"                
 [7] "0001"                      "0003"                      "0009"                     
[10] "0015"
```

I want to run a report on each of the column names that are numbers:

```
for(DiscID in colnames(spreadResults[7:length(spreadResults)]))
{ 
  #DiscIDcol <- match(DiscID,names(spreadResults))
  colID <- as.name(DiscID)
  print(colID)
  print(DiscID)

  #get data into format suitable for creating tables
  temp <- spreadResults %>% select(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, colID) %>% 
      filter_(!is.na(colID)) %>%
      group_by_(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, colID) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      ungroup()
}
```

But I get:

```
`0001`
[1] "0001"
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  colID
```

However, if I use back ticks `` and explicitly name the column

```
temp <- spreadResults %>% select(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, `0001`)
```

It's fine. Is there a way of addressing column names with variables? I know you can use matches(DiscID) within select(), but matches(...) doesn't work in group_by, spread etc

the first five rows of the data frame I'm dealing with, from dput()

```
structure(list(
PupilMatchingRefAnonymous = c(12345L, 12346L, 12347L, 12348L, 12349L), 
GENDER = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
URN = c(123456L, 123456L, 123456L, 123456L, 123456L), 
KS2Eng = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L), 
KS2Mat = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L), 
EVERFSM_6 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
`0001` = c(66, 44, NA_real_, 55, 66),
`0003` = c(22, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
`0009` = c(NA_real_, 66, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
`0015` = c(33, NA_real_, 55, NA_real_, NA_real_)), 
.Names = c("PupilMatchingRefAnonymous", "GENDER", "URN", "KS2Eng", "KS2Mat", "EVERFSM_6", 
"0001", "0003", "0009", "0015"), 
row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output:

```
  GENDER EVERFSM_6  0001     n
  (fctr)     (int) (dbl) (int)
1      F         0    55     1
2      F         1    66     1
3      M         1    44     1
4      M         1    66     1
```

Comment: Easiest thing is probably to change column names to have a leading character.

Comment: It's not about the numbers (though that will generally be a pain); it's about non-standard eval. `dplyr` functions take unquoted column names by default, so if you want to pass them something else, you need to use the SE versions, which end with an underscore (`select_`).

Comment: running spreadResults <- rename(spreadResults, "n0001" = `0001`), then running the code again, still brings up the same error on n0001. I can rename but no difference

Comment: You just need `select_`. As in `spreadResults %>% select_(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, colID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To program with arbitrary column names in `dplyr`, you need to use the standard-eval versions of the functions, which end in `_`, so your variables don't get interpreted as column names by the NSE versions. (For more on NSE, see [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).)

The syntax should look something like:

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

iris %>% select_(.dots = cols) %>% head()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5
# 2          4.9         3.0
# 3          4.7         3.2
# 4          4.6         3.1
# 5          5.0         3.6
# 6          5.4         3.9
```

If you have fixed column names you need as well, insert them into your character vector/list or quote them with `''`, `""`, `quote`, or `~`:

```
iris %>% select_(~Species, .dots = cols) %>% head()
#   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1  setosa          5.1         3.5
# 2  setosa          4.9         3.0
# 3  setosa          4.7         3.2
# 4  setosa          4.6         3.1
# 5  setosa          5.0         3.6
# 6  setosa          5.4         3.9
```

Comment: have updated the question with the dput output. Your answer is very close, but I'm getting issues when I move beyond the select. When DiscID == "0001", running 
cols <- c("GENDER", "EVERFSM_6", DiscID)
spreadResults %>% select_(.dots = cols) %>% filter_(!is.na(DiscID))
pulls the first column: PupilMatchingRefAnonymous

Comment: alternatively. setting colID <- as.name(DiscID)
    cols <- c("GENDER", "EVERFSM_6", colID)
    temp <- spreadResults %>% select_(.dots = cols) %>% 
      filter_(!is.na(c(colID)))

the select works, but the filter_doesn't fire and doesn't complain either

Comment: SE `filter_` is sort of a pain, as far as I've seen. You can either use `interp`/`substitute` or just `paste`: `df %>% select_(.dots = cols) %>% filter_(paste('!is.na(', DiscID, ')'))`

Comment: thanks alistaire. It works a treat, slight mistype on the filter_ code, you need a paste0 and the back ticks df %>% select_(.dots = cols) %>% 
      filter_(paste0('!is.na(`', DiscID, '`)'))

Answer (score 3):

The help of `select` suggests the use of `one_of`. It works in the following example:

```
df <- data.frame("a" = 1:3 , "b"  = 3:5)
names(df)[1] <- "243234" # rename, to a numeric string

var <- names(df)[1] 

library(dplyr)

df %>% select( one_of(var) )
```

You can also see that the problem is not in your numeric names, but in the way you called select:

```
var <- names(df)[2] # use the column named "b"
df %>% select( one_of(var) )
  b
1 3
2 4
3 5
df %>% select( var)
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  var
```

Comment: I should have made my question clearer, matches() also works inside select, but doesn't work in group_by, spread etc. It appears that there are similar problems with one_of() inside these other functions

Comment: thanks, but your objective is still very vague. please add some desired output.

Comment: have given the desired output, that is achieved when using: spreadResults %>% select(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, `0001`) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(`0001`)) %>% 
      #head()
      group_by(GENDER, EVERFSM_6, `0001`) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
      ungroup() (note that back ticks don't show in coide preview)